# Data Not Being Sent Back On Ajax Request

Tags: php, ajax

I'm sending an AJAX request to my server to create a new entry in my database, then return the id of the created entry. When I run my code, the console says that `response` is undefined. Any idea why? Here's my code:

**Client:**

```
var tempId;

     var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: {""},
        url: 'file.php?recID=' + recID,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            tempId = response.recentId;
        }
    });
```

**Server:**

```
$recID = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "recID", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $curTime = time();
    $fdArray['recentId'] = array();

    //Create new entry
    $stmt = $page->dbm->prepare("INSERT INTO table(cid, approved, active, created) VALUES ('$recID', '0', '0', ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $curTime);
    if($stmt->execute()) { $code = 204; } else { $code = 500; echo "Data failed to save!"; }

    //Get created entry
    $contentQuery = $page->dbm->query("SELECT id, created FROM table WHERE cid = '$recID' ORDER BY created DESC");
    $content = $contentQuery->fetch_object();
    array_push($fdarray['recentId'], $content->id);
    echo json_encode($fdArray);

    http_response_code($code);
```

Comment: Have you checked your error log? If the request is being made (you can inspect that too in the browser) we can assume the PHP script is erring out. What is the HTTP response code?

Comment: What do you get if you simply exit after you echo the json on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized my original answer is incorrect, because then the `success` callback would not have been called *at all*.

The actual problem is that you are returning a [status code `204`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204), which means "No Content". `$.ajax()` (and/or the underlying `XMLHttpRequest`) respects this and doesn't process any available body data.

---

*Original answer:*

If [output buffering](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) is disabled, you cannot set the HTTP response code after you have already sent out any body data, because HTTP response headers cannot be sent after the HTTP response body.

Try to set the HTTP response code *before* you send out any data, for instance like:

```
http_response_code($code);
echo json_encode($fdArray);
```

---

It could very well be that there's other errors in your script as well. For instance, where is `$recID` coming from? Look into your error logs.

---

As a side note, why are you not binding `$recID` to your prepared statement as well, instead of inserting it directly into your query string? This is a security concern. You are already using prepared statements, so use them properly. :)

Comment: I'm getting $recID from the URL, forgot the include that line. I'll edit my post for anyone in the future. Thank you for pointing out not binding $recID. Not returning a response code seems to have fixed my issue, so thank you!